# Need help in generating a formula for nextID excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a an excel sheet with the following columns
ID, City, Record no. 
I need to generate a column called Next ID based on the record number.
i.e if the city is same I need to populate the Next ID column with the ID of the previous record number.

Is there a way to do this in excel?

Here is the sample data, with the Next Column populated manually for reference:

```
ID  City    Record no.  **Next ID
121 Paris     3 
122 Paris     2          121
123 Paris     1          122
124 New York  2 
125 New York  1          124
```

Please see attached image

[image: Sample data for reference]

I've edit the question as I was not able to add a image in the comments. My data is not sorted so I used the second formula. This works for some cases but doesn't work for others. see the pink colored cells which should have a value but do not.
[image: After using formula]

Comment: Ummmmm...Just when through your history, you know you are supposed to mark the correct answers as such, by clicking the check mark by the answer?  If you do not people will stop answering you questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is always sorted use this:

```
=IF(B2=B1,A1,"")
```

in D2 and copy/drag down

[image]

---

If not sorted then use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$6)/(($C$2:$C$6=C2+1)*($B$2:$B$6=B2)),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works in some cases.
I've attached another image to the question.

Comment: The formula works for me if you make the cell references the correct size.  The formula I gave you only refers from row 2 to row 6.  You will need to enlarge those references to reference the whole data set. https://imgur.com/a/Cc0v5